# Getting 401 when signing HTTP message with signpost

Tags: java, oauth, httpurlconnection, signpost, appdirect

I am integrating my web app with [AppDirect](https://www.appdirect.com/),
for this I created a java rs API using jersey.

When I subscribe to an event, I get a map containing the oauth values (key and secret) to sign my request and an event url to which I issue a sign fetch to.

I am getting those values (oauth and eventurl) as expected.

Now when I try to issue a signed fetch using the library [signpost](https://code.google.com/archive/p/oauth-signpost/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki), I use the following code:

```
OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumer_key, secret);
// create an HTTP request to a protected resource
URL url = new URL(eventUrl);
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// sign the request
consumer.sign(request);

// send the request
request.connect();
```

I get this error message:

```
getResponseMessage: Unauthorized
getresponsecode: 401
```

I also tried with the following test values:

1. url = "https://www.appdirect.com/api/integration/v1/events/dummyOrder";
2. dummyKey = "Dummy";
3. dummySecret = "secret";
   But I got the same result.

Please how can I fix it?

I also tried and adding this:

```
request.setRequestMethod("GET");         

request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth");

request.setRequestProperty("Host", "...");

request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");         

request.setRequestProperty("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);

request.setRequestProperty("oauth_signature", oauth_signature);

request.setRequestProperty("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);

request.setRequestProperty("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);

request.setRequestProperty("oauth_version", oauth_version);
```

also tried with `key:secret` in the Authorization property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Dummy keys (oauth)]

[image: No-auth]

Here is a behavior of this service when testing via Postman Chrome extension.
If you are using OAuth provider, so you need to get valid api-key for AppDirect and secret.

BTW second screenshot shows you don't need to send an OAuth token to appdirect to https://www.appdirect.com/api/integration/v1/events/dummyOrder, because it authorizes any url.

So, according to your notes, you have to add proper(secret and key) and then AppDirect OAuth server will return you a valid token which you will use when addressing AppDirect's repositories. Or you may send key-secret with each request.

Comment: yes, I already use OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumer_key, secret); I will add some code

Comment: I do have a valid consumer key and secret and I am passing it in my DefaultOAuthConsumer object. Where else shall I use it?

Comment: Just try the same way I tried. Use postman or another rest-client. Add credentials you used from java-code. Post the result here.

Comment: actually, it works with test keys but not with the ones that they provided are not working, thanks anyway